# Efficient parsing of a string into float array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization

The Collada file format contains lots of data which is stored as whitespace delimited list of float/int/boolean values. These lists can be *huge*. We parse these lists in JavaScript using roughly the following code:

```
var floats = input.split(' ').map(parseFloat)
```

But this generates a lot of garbage because the huge input string is split into thousands of individual small strings. Is there a way to avoid that? Something like a parseFloat() function which I can point at a offset within an existing string, and so avoid generating the garbage.

Comment: Why are the rest of them garbage? Do you only need one value at a time?

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage"? Are you talking about memory usage, as in that temporary array of strings that will need to be garbage-collected, or just garbage as in values you don't want? There is no `parseFloat()` variation that extracts from an offset in a string. You could manually extract substrings using `.indexOf()` and `.substr()` in a loop or something, but that would create just as many strings overall (they just wouldn't all be held in an array simultaneously). Is the current code performing badly?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the small temporary strings that `split()` creates. `substring()` will also create those. And I need all the floats.

Comment: There's no way to avoid creating those temporary strings, but an array with a few thousand short strings shouldn't be a problem - are you experiencing memory problems?

Answer (score 2):

If you prefix your string with one space, you can use this to get the first number out of the string:

```
var start = 0 // Initial search offset.
var firstOccurence = input.indexOf(' ', start);
//Get the substring from the first occurrence of ' ' after start, to the next one, and parse it as a float.
parseFloat(input.substring(firstOccurence , input.indexOf(' ', firstOccurence+1)));
```

Then, you can use the following to get the numbers after that, out of the string:

```
firstOccurence = t.indexOf(' ', firstOccurence+1);
parseFloat(t.substring(firstOccurence , t.indexOf(' ', firstOccurence+1)));
```

Using this in a loop, you can search through your list, and you can start searching the list at a specified index. You can't however, ask for the 7th float in the list, for example. The only reliable way to do that is to use `.split(' ')`, or to use the above code in a loop.

To find the `n`th float in the input, you can use the following:

```
for(var i = 0, previousIndex = 0; i < n; i++){
    previousIndex = input.indexOf(' ', previousIndex + 1);
}
var float = parseFloat(input.substring(previousIndex, input.indexOf(' ',  previousIndex + 1)));
```

Comment: `++lastIndex` doesn't actually change the value of `lastIndex`, since it is part of the right hand side of an assignment to `lastIndex`

Comment: Just tried in the chrome console. pre-incrementing a variable on the right hand-side DOES change the value of the variable.`var x = 0; var v = ++x; x //=>1; v //=>1;`

Comment: Hm, that's a good point. I'd still prefer to use +1 here, though. Other users might copy/paste/edit...

Comment: @Bruno Nope, try `var v= 0; v = v++;`. It will result in v being zero. The original isn't affected, but you're using it as the RHS of a *different* assignment.

Comment: `v = 0;
v = ++v;
v = ++v;
//=> 0, 1, 2`
Both Chrome and Firefox increment v.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, that is because `v=++v` is equivalent to `v = v + 1`, which works out to `0+1`. If the increment changed the original value you would get 2 after the first assignment: `v+=1; v = v+1 ` which works out to `1+1`

Comment: @Cerbrus In other words `v = 0; v = ++v; v = ++v;` is equivalent to `v=0; v= v + 1; v = v + 1;`

Comment: Hm, it appears your _@Bruno Nope <...>_ was incorrect. Bruno was talking about ++v, but you turned it around into v++.
`v = 0; v = ++v; v = ++v; //returns 2`
`v = 0; v = v++; v = v++; //returns 0`
That was exactly what I was saying, and why I think it was a bad idea to use the `++` instead of simply `+ 1`. `++v`. `++v` increments `v`, stores the new value, then returns it.

Comment: @Cerbrus Either way, it doesn't matter. `++v` affects the original value no more than `v++` does. They just return in one case an incremented value, and in the other case a non incremented value when on the RHS of an assignment. To understand this better have a look at the spec on http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1

Comment: @Cerbrus ok so v++ on its own will increment v, basically `v = v + 1`. On the right handside it doesn't and essentially resolves to `( v + 1 )`. Thanks for explaining that :)

Comment: @Cerbrus Perhaps this will explain it better. What is the output you expect when doing this: `var v= 0; v= ++v + ++v + ++v;`

Comment: @Asad That will translate to `v = ( 0 + 1 ) + ( 0 + 1 ) + ( 0 + 1 );` and **NOT** `v = ( v = 0 + 1 ) + ( v = 0 + 1 ) + ( v = 0 + 1 );`. Brilliant, you learn something everyday :)

Comment: @Bruno Correct, but if we were using `x = ++v + ++v + ++v` something different would happen. It would then become equivalent to `x= (v = v + 1) + (v = v + 1) + (v = v + 1)`. You can try this in your console to verify it is equivalent. Yes, exactly!

Comment: `v = (0+1) + ((0+1)+1) + (((0+1)+1)+1);` That would be 6, because `++v` saves the incremented var before returning it. Edit: my console agrees with me... It doesn't matter is you use `x =` or `v =`: `var v = 0; v = ++v + ++v + ++v;` (And that's both FireFox and Chrome, again)

Comment: @Cerbrus I'll open a question on this so we can find out which one of us is correct. How's that sound?

Comment: *nods* Please link me to it.

Comment: Nooooo way! That is `x = ( v = 0 + 1 ) + ( v = 1 + 1 ) + ( v = 2 + 1 )`. So `x = 1 + 2 + 3 //=> 6 and y = 3`. My mind has been blown away.

Comment: @Cerbrus Here's the link. Please edit the question if I have somehow misrepresented or misunderstood your position. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565217/javascript-increment-while-assigning

Comment: @Asad That actually proves what I initially said. This answer originally had a pre-increment operation which as you have stated changes the value of v. So `var v = 0; var x = parseFloat( ++v );` does in fact change the value of v to 1. The interesting discovery for me is that post-increment resolves to a value rather than changing v.

Comment: @Bruno I disagree that the value is changed (but *only* when assigning to itself, so that example with `x= ++v` is not valid). Cerbrus is the one who believes the operator reassigns the value.

Answer (score 2):

This function can handle multiple white spaces as well as input that does not parse as a float.

```
input = "123 123 123  foo", start = 0, end = 0, result = [], num;

// empty string evaluates to false
while( end < input.length ) {
    end = input.indexOf(" ", start );
    // -1 => only one element in input || end of the string has been reached
    if( end === -1 ) { end = input.length }
    num =  parseFloat( input.substring( start, end ) );
    // Should extracted string fail to parse then skip
    if( num ) result.push( num ); 
    // move forward or end will match current empty space
    start = end + 1;
}

result[2] // => "123";
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/H2ses/3/)

**UPDATE**

Just had a brainwave. Don't use the map function but just use the array created by splitting the string like so:

```
var floats = input.split(' ');
for( var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    input[i] = parseFloat( input[i] );
}
```

Comment: @wereHamster Does my last suggestion actually do what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
parseFloat(input.substring(5,10));
```

Where `5,10` are the starting and ending offsets of your desired chunk of string.