# Why the value plus plus at last is 100?

Tags: javascript

when i use ++ operator in javascript, why I get the value at last is 100 not 101?
I want to know the detail of the ++ operator in javascript?

```
let value = 100;
value = value++;
console.log(value); // 100 why the value is 100 at last
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565217/javascript-increment-while-assigning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you have the assignment operator, the right-hand operand is evaluated first, then that value is assigned to the receiver on the left.¹

So here's what happens in `value = value++`:

1. Read the value of `value` (`100`) and set it aside (since we'll need it in a minute).
2. Increase the value of `value` by one (making it `101`).
3. Take the value from #1 (`100`) as the result value of the right-hand operand.
4. Store that value in `value`.

---

¹ In specification terms it's *slightly* more complicated than that, but the details aren't important here.

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this, hence the CW. (I find that if I go hunting first, poor answers pile up...)

Comment: I can't actually find one that handles the assignment part (and don't want to spend more time looking). The two marked questions don't handle that part, but they do explain postfix increment, so...meh, close enough.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<value>++` returns the previous value and not the new one
If you want it to return the new value use `++<value>`